# Taxonomy tree does not fit in the page

Tags: tikz-trees

I have tried to draw the following tree but it is not fitting in one page and going out of the page.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        my node/.style={
            draw=gray,
            inner color=gray!5,
            outer color=gray!10,
            thick,
            minimum width=1cm,
%           rounded corners=3,
            text height=1.5ex,
            text depth=0ex,
            font=\sffamily,
            drop shadow,
        }
    }
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={%
            my node,
            l sep+=5pt,
            grow'=east,
            edge={gray, thick},
            parent anchor=east,
            child anchor=west,
            if n children=0{tier=last}{},
            edge path={
                \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(10pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
            if={isodd(n_children())}{
                for children={
                    if={equal(n,(n_children("!u")+1)/2)}{calign with current}{}
                }
            }{}
        }
        [Nwdefd  efdewf
        [Exact 
        [Tewewf fewfew Methods[feweff][fewfmqwd][Quad-Trees][Ohyyyhyrttge][Cregregrgregregerg][regrgfregregreggreg][regrefwfwefefTrees]][Filtereferfr anrfrfd Verefr[Fast Nreewewewfew Neiuwefewr][Principle Axdwfeis Searewfrefrch Tewffrees][Orrefrefrfrthogonal Sewferfearch Trrefrefreees][Hyyrhyhtyperplane Bounfwewfewewds+]]]
        [Apewfewproxewfewewewimate Nearewfewfest Neigewewfewhbour Seefewewewarch
        [Hashewfewfing Baewfewfewsed[Locaeewfewlity Sensiewfewfetive Haewfewfshing][Leaewfweffewrning to Hewfewfewfewash]][Paewfewewfrtition Bawefewqwewsed[Baewfwwfelancewewed Box][Baewfeweewewewlanced Aewfwspeewfewct Ratewfio]][Grewfewfaph Based[Deewfewlewfewfeaewfewunay graphs][ navigaewfewewfble small worewfwefld gewffewraeffewph]]]]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Kindly provide other solutions as the one given below is not working properly

Comment: Using `\-` for hyphenation is a very basic approach in LaTeX and in order to make the diagram less wide you probably will need it anyways. So, you better try to find out why this is not working in your case. I cannot reproduce the problem you describe with the above MWE and thus I am unable to help you. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need that much text inside the nodes, you should probably use a smaller font. Then, I would suggest that you remove the `text depth` option and add a `text width` option instead to enable line breaking. Hyphenation will work once proper English words (or words from another existing human languange) are used and the text will then fit the boxes properly.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        my node/.style={
            draw=gray,
            inner color=gray!5,
            outer color=gray!10,
            thick,
            minimum width=1cm,
%           rounded corners=3,
            text height=1.5ex,
%           text depth=0ex,
            text width=2cm,
            font=\sffamily\scriptsize,
            drop shadow,
        }
    }
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={%
            my node,
            l sep+=5pt,
            grow'=east,
            edge={gray, thick},
            parent anchor=east,
            child anchor=west,
            if n children=0{tier=last}{},
            edge path={
                \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(10pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
            if={isodd(n_children())}{
                for children={
                    if={equal(n,(n_children("!u")+1)/2)}{calign with current}{}
                }
            }{}
        }
        [Nwdefd  efdewf
        [Exact 
        [Tewewf fewfew Methods[feweff][fewfmqwd][Quad-Trees][Ohyyyhyrttge][Cregregrgregregerg][regrgfregregreggreg][regrefwfwefefTrees]][Filtereferfr anrfrfd Verefr[Fast Nreewewewfew Neiuwefewr][Principle Axdwfeis Searewfrefrch Tewffrees][Orrefrefrfrthogonal Sewferfearch Trrefrefreees][Hyyrhyhtyperplane Bounfwewfewewds+]]]
        [Apewfewproxewfewewewimate Nearewfewfest Neigewewfewhbour Seefewewewarch
        [Hashewfewfing Baewfewfewsed[Locaeewfewlity Sensiewfewfetive Haewfewfshing][Leaewfweffewrning to Hewfewfewfewash]][Paewfewewfrtition Bawefewqwewsed[Baewfwwfelancewewed Box][Baewfeweewewewlanced Aewfwspeewfewct Ratewfio]][Grewfewfaph Based[Deewfewlewfewfeaewfewunay graphs][ navigaewfewewfble small worewfwefld gewffewraeffewph]]]]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but some text is going out of the box

Comment: Yes, as I said: Once you use proper English words, the text will be hyphenated properly and adjust to fit in the boxes. TeX has a hard time to hyphenate nonsense words like "Deewfewlewfewfeaewfewunay". If you really want to use such words, you need to use `\-` to let TeX know about possible points for hyphenation.

Comment: Do you mean Deewfewlewfew \- feaewfewunay? it is not working.

Comment: Yes, but without the spaces. What exactly is not working? It works fine for me.

Comment: Deewfewlewfew\-feaewfewunay is going out of the box.

Comment: Do you perhaps use another document class or did you add some other packages? In the above code it should work fine. But do you really want to use these words? If they are just placeholders, why not just place more spaces?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137577/discussion-between-shi-and-jasper-habicht).

Comment: Is it ok to ask if the words used here are a real language or just gibberish?

Comment: I don't know why `\-` for custom hyphenation is not working for you, sorry! For me it works like a charm.